# Way to remove visitor pattern redundancy?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

So I'm playing around with the visitor pattern for the first time, and wonder why I have to write the accept function multiple times for each derived class.

```
class object
{
public:
    virtual void accept(visitor *v) { v->visit(this); }

// ....
};

class derived : public object
{
public:
    void accept(visitor *v) override { v->visit(this); } // redundancy in my eyes!!
    // ...
};
```

Do I really have to define that accept function for every single visitable? Is there a way to just write it once in the base class and have *this* refer to the particular derived class pointer without having to cast?

Comment: If the derived class behaves exactly the same way as the base class, then it is redundant and you can get rid of it. If they don't then it is not redundant. Don't forget the `virtual` keyword if they are different.

Comment: @user4581301 well the thing is that *this* has to be of type derved* and not object*.

Comment: The visitor pattern is supposed to work with any combination of types. Why are you expecting it to work any different just because you are using derived classes?

Answer (score 4):

What is not redundant is the type of `*this`. In the base class the type of `*this` is `object`. In the derived class the type of `*this` is `derived`. This difference is what makes the visitor pattern usefull.

You can avoid to reimplement a function in all derived classes thanks to CRTP:

```
class base_acceptor{
    public:
        virtual void accept(visitor *v) {v->accept(*this);}
    };
template<class Derived, class...Bases>
class acceptor_implementer
  : public Bases...
  {
     void accept(visitor *v) override {
        assert(dynamic_cast<Derived*>(this)!=nullptr);
        v->accept(static_cast<Derived&>(*this));
        }
   };

 class acceptor1
    :acceptor_implementer<acceptor1,base_acceptor>
    {};
 class acceptor2
    :acceptor_implementer<acceptor2,base_acceptor>
    {};
 class acceptor11
    :acceptor_implementer<acceptor11,acceptor1>
    {};
```